# How to show columnheader in XLS view for JasperReports

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I have configured *JasperReports* successsfully on *Spring MVC*.
The problems is that when I export as XLS, it does not show the columns headers.
I want the headers to show.
What parameters do I need to add to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues is resolved I mistakenly put an horizontal rule. I have now removed the HR and everything is fine.